Solving $\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+4\frac{dy}{dt}+4y=e^{-2t}$ Using Laplace Transforms
$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+4\frac{dy}{dt}+4y=e^{-2t},y(0)=1,y'(0)=0$$
I have made the following attempt below. I am looking to see if I went wrong anywhere, as I don't have much experience using Laplace Transforms.
$$y'' +4y'+4y=e^{-2t}$$
$$\mathcal L \lbrace y''+4y'+4y \rbrace =\mathcal L \lbrace e^{-2t} \rbrace $$
$$\mathcal L \lbrace y'' \rbrace + 4\mathcal L \lbrace y' \rbrace + 4\mathcal L \lbrace y \rbrace =\mathcal L \lbrace e^{-2t} \rbrace $$
Using the Laplace table provided to me I found:
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal L \lbrace y'' \rbrace & : s^2\mathcal L \lbrace y \rbrace - sy(0)-y'(0) \newline
\mathcal L \lbrace y' \rbrace & : s\mathcal L \lbrace y \rbrace - y(0) \newline
\mathcal L \lbrace e^{-2t} \rbrace & : \frac{1}{s+2}
\end{align}$$
After substituting the Laplace Transforms I was left with
$$s^2\mathcal L \lbrace y \rbrace -sy(0)-y'(0)+4[s\mathcal L \lbrace y \rbrace -y(0)]+4\mathcal L \lbrace y \rbrace = \frac{1}{s+2}$$
I continued by plugging in the given initial conditions and isolating $\mathcal L\lbrace y\rbrace$
$$s^2\mathcal L \lbrace y \rbrace -s\cdot1-0+4[s\mathcal L \lbrace y \rbrace -1]+4\mathcal L \lbrace y \rbrace = \frac{1}{s+2}$$
$$s^2\mathcal L \lbrace y \rbrace -s+4s\mathcal L \lbrace y \rbrace -4+4\mathcal L \lbrace y \rbrace = \frac{1}{s+2}$$
$$s^2\mathcal L \lbrace y \rbrace + 4s\mathcal L \lbrace y \rbrace + 4\mathcal L \lbrace y \rbrace = \frac{1}{s+2} +s+4$$
$$\mathcal L \lbrace y \rbrace(s^2+4s+4)=\frac{1}{s+2} +s+4$$
$$\mathcal L \lbrace y \rbrace = \frac{s^2+6s+9}{(s+2)(s^2+4s+4)}$$
This is where I feel I might have made a mistake, I used partial fractions here.
$$\frac{s^2+6s+9}{(s+2)^3} = \frac{a_0}{s+2} + \frac{a_1}{(s+2)^2} + \frac{a_2}{(s+2)^3}$$
$$s^2+6s+9=a_0(s+2)^2+a_1(s+2)+a_2$$
$$(-2)^2+6(-2)+9=a_0((-2)+2)^2+a_1((-2)+2)+a_2$$ $$a_2=1$$
$$s^2+6s+9=a_0(s+2)^2+a_1(s+2)+1$$
$$s^2+6s+9=a_0s^2+4a_0s+4a_0+a_1s+2a_1+1$$
$$s^2+6s+9=a_0s^2+s(4a_0+a_1)+(4a_0+2a_1+1)$$
Leaving us with a system of equations
$$\begin{bmatrix}
4a_0 + 2a_1 + 1 = 9 \newline
4a_0 + a_1 = 6 \newline
a_0 = 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$a_0=1,a_1=2,a_2=1$$
$$ \mathcal L \lbrace y \rbrace = \frac{1}{s+2} + \frac{2}{(s+2)^2}+\frac{1}{(s+2)^3}$$
$$y = \mathcal L^{-1} \left\lbrace\frac{1}{s+2} + \frac{2}{(s+2)^2}+\frac{1}{(s+2)^3}\right\rbrace$$
$$y= \mathcal L^{-1} \left\lbrace \frac{1}{s+2} \right\rbrace+\mathcal L^{-1}\left\lbrace\frac{2}{(s+2)^2} \right\rbrace+\mathcal L^{-1}\left\lbrace\frac{1}{(s+2)^3}\right\rbrace$$
Here I consulted my Laplace Transform table again.
$$\mathcal L^{-1} \left\lbrace \frac{1}{s-a} \right\rbrace = e^{at} \dots \mathcal L^{-1} \left\lbrace \frac{1}{s+2} \right\rbrace = e^{-2t}$$
$$\mathcal L^{-1}\left\lbrace F(s-a) \right\rbrace = e^{at}f(t) \dots \mathcal L^{-1}\left\lbrace\frac{2}{(s+2)^2} \right\rbrace = e^{-2t}\mathcal L^{-1}\left\lbrace \frac{2}{s^2} \right\rbrace = e^{-2t}\cdot2t$$
$$\mathcal L^{-1}\left\lbrace F(s-a) \right\rbrace = e^{at}f(t)\dots\mathcal L^{-1}\left\lbrace\frac{1}{(s+2)^3}\right\rbrace = e^{-2t}\mathcal L^{-1}\left\lbrace \frac{1}{s^3} \right\rbrace = \frac{e^{-2t}t^2}{2}$$
After substituting these values into $y= \mathcal L^{-1} \left\lbrace \frac{1}{s+2} \right\rbrace+\mathcal L^{-1}\left\lbrace\frac{2}{(s+2)^2} \right\rbrace+\mathcal L^{-1}\left\lbrace\frac{1}{(s+2)^3}\right\rbrace$ I found the final equation to be:
$$y=e^{-2t}+e^{-2t}\cdot2t+\frac{e^{-2t}t^2}{2}$$

Your work is fine, though you probably meant $\frac{d^2y}{d\color{red}{t}^2}$, not $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ etc. You can always verify by plugging the solution back into the ODE.

To have a short partial fraction decomposition, note that $$\frac{(s+3)^2}{(s+2)^3}=\frac{(\ (s+2)+1\ )^2}{(s+2)^3}=\frac{(s+2)^2+2(s+2)+1}{(s+2)^3}\ ,$$and it immediately comes to the split.
